# Remove duplicates failing VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In this code, i want it to check if column "B" has duplicates - If it does, I should remove that Cell + 2 cells to the right.

So if (B12) = (B13)  it should remove (B13), (B14), (B15)

The duplicateremover is in the bottom of the code, and its not working. There should be around 50 different numbers for the B-column, but it only finds 2.

```
Sub Expa()

Sheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Select
'For / Next unik liste
For i = 2 To 18288
If IsEmpty(Sheets("Base").Cells(i, 8)) = True Then
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 2)
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 9)
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Cells(i, 4) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 10)
End If
Next i

'For / Next fuld liste
For i = 2 To 18288
If IsEmpty(Sheets("Base").Cells(i, 8)) = True Then
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Cells(i, 7) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 2)
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Cells(i, 8) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 9)
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Cells(i, 9) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 10)
End If
Next i

'Overskrifter unik liste
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Cells(1, 2).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 2) = "Unik liste"
Cells(2, 2) = "PROGRAM_CODE"
Cells(2, 3) = "FACULTY_ID"
Cells(2, 4) = "PROGRAM_TYPE_LETTER"

'Overskrifter fuld liste
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Cells(1, 6).Font.Bold = True '
Cells(1, 6) = "Fuld liste"
Cells(2, 7) = "PROGRAM_CODE"
Cells(2, 8) = "FACULTY_ID"
Cells(2, 9) = "PROGRAM_TYPE_LETTER"

'Sorterer for overblik unik liste
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
"B2:B18288"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Sort
.SetRange Range("B2:E18288")
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Columns("A:F").AutoFit

'Sorterer for overblik fuld liste
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
"G2:G18288"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Sort
.SetRange Range("G2:J18288")
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
Worksheets("STUDYBOARD_ID Blank").Columns("F:J").AutoFit


Dim Information1 As Range
Dim Information2 As Long

Information2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set Information1 = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:D" & Information2)
Information1.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes



End Sub
```

Comment: Use `[F8]` to step through the code line by line to find out more about what's "not working" in that section.  Hover the mouse over variables to see what their value is at that point.  More debugging tips from [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Comment: I dont think you read my question. I know that the whole code works except the last 5 lines :-)

Comment: Please remove all the code that is not relevant to your question. Have you tried to do the `RemoveDuplicate` manually in Excel? Have you checked if your Range is correct? Advice: Name your variables a little bit more meaningful than `information`, especially if you expect that someone will ever see your code...

Answer (score 0):

IF Column B is the one who should be checked for dublicates then code should look like this:

```
Information1.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
```

Column 3 is C.